# How to Center align text inTextVIew in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align a text in textview.Here My code:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/log"
        android:onClick="home"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/electronic1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="shopByCategory"
            android:text="Electronic"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fashion"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="shopByCategory"
            android:text="Fashion &amp; Lifestyle "/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/deal"
            android:onClick="deal"
            android:text="@string/today_deals"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="home"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/track"
            android:text="@string/track_your_order"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="legal"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/legal"
            android:text="@string/legal"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rate1"
            android:text="@string/rate_this_app"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="query"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/query"
            android:text="@string/any_other_query"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/query"
            android:text="@string/follow_us_on_twitter"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb"
            android:text="@string/follow_us_on_facebook"/>





    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my snapshot:-
[image]

I couldn't able to set text in center with it's icon in Menu. So please provide proper solution for this problem. I want it as like Electronic text is show in center with his icon.

Comment: Try my code http://stackoverflow.com/a/33781647/5333147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nine_demo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Hello" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="shopByCategory"
        android:text="Shop By Category"/>
```

Comment: What is about icon. You can't add icon.

Comment: use 'android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"'

Comment: No its not working I talking about those textview icon is added see my snapshot

Comment: Yeah, take that image and textview in one layout and apply android:gravity="center_vertical" to that textview

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to your parent `LinearLayout`, and then change the width of the `TextView` to `wrap_content`

Such as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/electronic1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="shopByCategory"
        android:text="Electronic"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I add icon when its not align center add icon them check

Comment: I already give width my parent center you read my all question.

Comment: Read my answer and try understand it. I dont mean the ```LinearLayout``` at the top, but the one that is surrounding the ```TextViews```'s

Comment: Did you set the width of the TextView to wrap_content?!

Comment: You can't understand my problem I want to set electronic text center.

Comment: Well you cant explain your problem then

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:gravity="center" with Horizontal gravity in your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:gravity="center-horizontal"`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/log"
        android:onClick="home"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/electronic1"
            android:gravity="center-horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="shopByCategory"
            android:text="Electronic"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fashion"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="shopByCategory"
            android:text="Fashion &amp; Lifestyle "/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/deal"
            android:onClick="deal"
            android:text="@string/today_deals"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="home"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/track"
            android:text="@string/track_your_order"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="legal"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/legal"
            android:text="@string/legal"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rate1"
            android:text="@string/rate_this_app"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="query"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/query"
            android:text="@string/any_other_query"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/query"
            android:text="@string/follow_us_on_twitter"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb"
            android:text="@string/follow_us_on_facebook"/>





    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```